# "const config = new Config()" not defined

Tags: node.js, adyen

I'm quite new to NodeJS and I try to follow an example setting up a payment solution provided by Adyen. In their example code they give me this:

```
const config = new Config();
config.apiKey = MY_API_KEY;
config.merchantAccount = MY_ACCOUNT;
const client = new Client({ config });
client.setEnvironment("TEST");
const checkout = new CheckoutAPI(client);
const paymentsResponse = checkout.paymentMethods({
    amount: {
        currency: "EUR",
        value: 1000,
    },
    countryCode: "NL",
    channel: "Web",
    merchantAccount: config.merchantAccount
}).then(res => res);
```

However (maybe not so surprising) I get the following error:

> const config = new Config();
>                  ^
>
> ReferenceError: Config is not defined

What should Config() be here? Should I define a new class? (class Config {}?) Or am I missing something? Like something to include? Same for client, how can I call .setEnvironment if Client is a class I create?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out you are supposed to import [@adyen/api-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adyen/api-library) with:

```
npm install --save @adyen/api-library
```

[Source](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/libraries)

Comment: As of npm@5 you don't need to add `--save`. Saving is default behavior since then.

Answer (score 0):

After [installing the API library](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-node-api-library#npm), you can include the modules:

```
const {Client, Config, CheckoutAPI} = require('@adyen/api-library');
```

Just place it at the top of the file where the rest of your code lives (i.e., where you make that `checkout.paymentMethods()` call), and you should be good to go!